# How to stop .py file from closing after opening? using python 3.9?

Tags: python-3.x, new-operator

My .py file keeps closing after it is opened. I understand it happens because the code is already run, but what can I do to stop this from happening? I have tried using the input() function but that is not helping. Is there any other way I can fix this, and is there any underlying problem that is causing this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: instead of double clicking .py, you can try right click and click edit with IDLE and Click F5 to run the code

Answer (score 0):

You can run the file using -i flag:

```
python -i script.py
```

The input() method you mentioned won't work if you hit a line that produced an error before you reached the input() line.